# Check if property is "T" using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm working on a project where I need to "translate" a .net class to typescript, bug I'm struggling with the following problem:

I'm trying to know at runtime if the property `AnotherClass.property1.genericProperty` is type `T`, but I'm always getting `MyClass` as type, what is the proper way to check it?

```
class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    public T genericProperty { get; set; }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public MyGenericClass<MyClass> property1 { get; set; }
    public MyClass regularProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Typescript that I expect:

```
interface MyGenericClass<T> {
    genericProperty: T;
}
```

What I'm getting at the moment:

```
interface MyGenericClass<T> {
    genericProperty: MyClass;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "generic property"; "genericProperty" is a regular (non-generic) property on a generic type - so, you'll need to check the declaring type; note also that the type can be **nested**, so it could be `class Foo<T> { class Bar { public T GenericProperty {get;set; } }` - so in the general case, you're going to have to work outwards until you've figured out what you need

Comment: So I need to check the `typeof(MyGenericClass<>).GetProperty("genericProperty")` instead?

Comment: oh, you're just after the fact that it is `T`? to do that, you need to make sure you're working on the generic type definition before you access the type; the `PropertyInfo` **in the generic type definition** should be typed as `T`, not typed as `MyClass` -  i.e. `GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetProperty("genericProperty").PropertyType.Name`

Comment: Exactly what I want, check if its `T`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if it is `T`".  It can't be anything else.

Comment: By "check if ts T" I mean if the class was written using "T" as type, to correct translate it to typescript source.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mark Gravell comment I was able to solve my problem, what I did:

Used

```
AnotherClass.property1.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetProperty("genericProperty").PropertyType.Name
```

instead of

```
AnotherClass.property1.PropertyType.GetProperty("genericProperty").PropertyType.Name
```

And now I'm getting the desired results.